# How I can create a javascript and html sales tax calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Ok my problem is, I want to create a sales tax calculator. When the user, put the price of a item ( example a ball that cost 7 dollars) calculate their final price with the tax of 12%.

But.. not just that, I want, if the user pick some item ( ball: $7, toy $4 and candy $2.. = $13) sum that item and add the sales tax ( $13 + 12%).

in my code I have the basic   structure dont worry for that.

Below i the code that i wrote, and dont works. I use HTML and Javascript.

Please help me.

```js
function CalculateIVU() {
  var price = document.forms.txts.value;
  var evaluation = price;
  var tax = 0.12 * evaluation;
  var final = +tax + +evaluation;
  document.getElementById('res').value = final;
}
```

```html
<form name="forms" id="forma">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>enter the value</label>
        <input type="text" name="txts" size=20>
        </br>
        <label>the tax is</label>
        <input type="text" name="resul" id="res">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one" VALUE="  1  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '1'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="two" VALUE="  2  " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '2'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="three" VALUE="  3  " OnClick="forms.txts.value  += '3'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="plus" VALUE="  +  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '+ '">
        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="four" VALUE="  4  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '4'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="five" VALUE="  5  " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '5'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="six" VALUE="  6  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '6'">

        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="seven" VALUE="  7  " OnClick="forms.txts.value+= '7'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="eight" VALUE="  8  " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '8'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="nine" VALUE="  9  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '9'">

        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" VALUE="  c  " OnClick="forms.txts.value = ''" OnClick="forms.resul.value = ''">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="zero" VALUE="  0  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '0'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="DoIt" VALUE="  =  " OnClick="CalculateIVU() = eval(forms.txts.value);">

        <br>
        <input type="button" id="input" value="Calcular" onClick='CalculateIVU();'>

      </td>
    </tr>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code as shown works for a single value. Is it just the part about the user entering multiple prices by pressing the `+` key that you're having trouble with?

Comment: ok.. I fix part of the code.. the only thing that I have problem is when a user wants to put 10 + 5 = 15

Comment: and I want the javascript sum the ( 10 + 5) and multiply by 15 * 0.12... and give the final price htat is 16.80. ( the sales tax is 1.80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as shown works for a single value when pressing the **Calcular** button. The **=** button doesn't work because `CalculateIVU() = eval(forms.txts.value);` is invalid JavaScript: you can't assign a function call equal to something.

Your use of `eval()` is a simple way to do a mathematical calculation on a string that you know is in the format `"1 + 2 + 3"`, however, this is an input field where the user can type *anything*, so if the user enters `"alert()"` then using `eval()` will actually display an alert box. Even if they've tried to enter just numbers separated by plus signs they might have a typo or have forgotten to enter a `+` or something, leading to a syntax error when `eval()`ed.

**You need to validate the input first.**

One way to do that is with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). It's easy to write a simple regular expression that tests for any characters other than digits, decimal points, spaces, and plus signs, e.g., `/[^ \d\.+]/`, but that isn't enough because you might still have an invalid expression made up of valid characters, e.g., `"1+++2+3...4"`. So here's a more complicated regex that should valid the whole string reasonably well:

```
/^\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?( *\+ *\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?)*$/
```

Explanation:

```
^                    // match beginning of string
\d{1,8}              // match from 1 to 8 digits
(\.\d{1,2})?         // match a . followed by 1 or 2 digits,
                     // where the parentheses and ? make it optional
(                    // start a group
 *\+ *               // match zero or more spaces then a + then zero or more spaces
\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?  // as above, match 1-8 digits optionally followed 
                     // by a . and 1-2 digits
)                    // end of group
*                    // match the last group zero or more times
$                    // match the end of the string
```

In other words, that regex will match `"1"` or `"1 + 1"` or `"1.2 + 2.3 + 3"` (etc.), but not `"1 + a"` or `"1 + + 1"` or `"1..2 + 3"`. You can use the [regex `.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to see if a given string matches a regular expression.

So putting that into your function:

```
function CalculateIVU() {
  var price = document.forms.txts.value;
  if (!/^\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?( *\+ *\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?)*$/.test(price)) {
    alert("Invalid input");
    return false;
  }
  var sum = eval(price); // at this point we know price can be eval()ed
  var tax = 0.12 * sum;
  var final = sum + tax;
  document.getElementById('res').value = final.toFixed(2); // round
}
```

Working demo:

```js
    function CalculateIVU() {
      var price = document.forms.txts.value;
      if (!/^\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?( *\+ *\d{1,8}(\.\d{1,2})?)*$/.test(price)) {
        alert("Invalid input");
        return false;
      }
      var sum = eval(price); // at this point we know price can be eval()ed
      var tax = 0.12 * sum;
      var final = sum + tax;
      document.getElementById('res').value = final.toFixed(2);  // round
    }
```

```html
<form name="forms" id="forma">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>enter the value</label>
        <input type="text" name="txts" size=20>
        </br>
        <label>the tax is</label>
        <input type="text" name="resul" id="res">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one" VALUE="  1  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '1'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="two" VALUE="  2  " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '2'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="three" VALUE="  3  " OnClick="forms.txts.value  += '3'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="plus" VALUE="  +  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '+ '">
        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="four" VALUE="  4  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '4'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="five" VALUE="  5  " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '5'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="six" VALUE="  6  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '6'">

        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="seven" VALUE="  7  " OnClick="forms.txts.value+= '7'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="eight" VALUE="  8  " OnCLick="forms.txts.value += '8'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="nine" VALUE="  9  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '9'">

        <br>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" VALUE="  c  " OnClick="forms.txts.value = ''" OnClick="forms.resul.value = ''">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="zero" VALUE="  0  " OnClick="forms.txts.value += '0'">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="DoIt" VALUE="  =  " OnClick="CalculateIVU();">

        <br>
        <input type="button" id="input" value="Calcular" onClick='CalculateIVU();'>

      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

P.S. For those who object to `eval()` for any purpose:

```
var sum = price.split(/ *\+ */).reduce(function(a,v) { return +a + +v; });
```

Comment: ok. this works. I very apreciated. Your the best person I never see before in JS. haha .... but I have other problem, when I put the code in the code editor works for browser... but when I put it on phonegap project,, dont work. you have an idea?